# How to get transparent corner using jquery corner plugin

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

I tried but it fills color at corners

[alt text http://stashbox.org/886089/11046214422-My-Desktop.png](http://stashbox.org/886089/11046214422-My-Desktop.png)

in place of white i need transparent corner with `0` opacity.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you just use the CSS3 border-radius property. For browsers that don't support it, they will have square corners. This is unfortunate, but saves you a lot of trouble. I looked at many rounded-corners jQuery plugins a while ago and the bottom line is, they were all broken in some browsers in one way or another. Using CSS3 border-radius fits the idea of progressive enhancement and is easy to build and maintain.

Comment: but css 3 borders can't make bevel coner

Answer (score 0):

http://methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner.html

> **Define an explicit background color in a parent element.** Safari requires that an ancestor of the element being adorned has a background color set. Just set the body to "background: #fff" if you don't need some other color.
>
> **Don't use a background image in the parent.** The adorned element effect sets pixels on the corners to the same color as the parent element. Those pixels are not transparent and will not show any background image that is used in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

@metal i found a way... Your back ground color seems to be in red right!..... If so go to corner.js and find #ffffff and replace it with your red color code...

find this line in ,

`return '#ffffff';` and change to `return '#ff0000';`

**EDIT:**

I found this in [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1468551/3395580.aspx)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test").corner();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body style="background-color: red;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="test" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; 
      background-color: white; opacity: 0.6;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60)">
         
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no actually my background is image. see this http://stashbox.org/883096/1104422739-My-Desktop.png

Comment: @metal sorry i got the point... Instead of white you want to set transparent right!

Comment: i need this transparent corner at `ul li.last`. I mean at last `li` of `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that this isn't possible because of the way it set.

It sets a div on top, and then uses a set of borders to create the effect.

You can change the color of the border, but if you make it transparent it will just show the absolutely positioned div below it.

Comment: http://www.curvycorners.net/

Sorry forgot to mention I use this... it will do what you need!